# how can I get statistique by dataframe in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I m working with a dataframe that have the schema

```
    df.printschema()

    root
    |-- _id: long (nullable = true)
    |-- d: array (nullable = true)
         |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
         |    |    |-- k: string (nullable = true)
         |    |    |-- v: string (nullable = true)
    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
```

for example 5 rows look like

```
    df.show(5)
   _id|d                                                              |c
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
   1 |[[k1,v1][k2,v2][k3,v3][k4,v4]                                   |c_1
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------  
   2 |[[k5,v5][k1,v1][k3,v31][k6,v6]                                  |c_2
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
   3 |[[k5,v51][k1,v13][k7,v7][k8,v8][[k9,v9][k10,v10][k3,v3][k4,v41] |c_3
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
   4 |[[k11,v11][k1,v1][k4,v4][k2,v28][[k9,v92][k10,v101][k3,v32]]    |c_1
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
   5 |[[k8,v81][k13,v31][k6,v66][k2,v2][[k9,v9][k15,v155][k4,v4]]     |c_4
```

I want to count for each [k*,v*] l'occuruence for each class c_* and the total occuruence. for exemple for c_1

```
    key_value |c_1_occ|totale_occ
    [k1,v1]   |[1,4]  |[1,2,4]
    [k2,v2]   |[1]    |[1,5]
    [k3,v3]   |[1]    |[1,3]
    [k4,v4]   |[1,4]  |[1,4,5]
    [k5,v5]   |[]     |[2]
    [k3,v31]  |[]     |[2]
    [k6,v6]   |[]     |[2]
    [k5,v51]  |[]     |[3]
    [k1,v13]  |[]     |[3]
    [k7,v7]   |[]     |[3]
    [k8,v8]   |[]     |[3]
    [k9,v9]   |[]     |[3,4]
    [k10,k10] |[]     |[3]
    [k4,v41]  |[]     |[3]
    [k11,v11] |[4]    |[4]
    [k2,v28]  |[4]    |[4]
    [k9,v92]  |[4]    |[4]
    [k10,v101]|[4]    |[4]
    [k3,v32]  |[4]    |[4]
    .
    .
    .
```

c_1_occ and total_occ represente listoff _id that [k*,v*] in c_1 and in the total class (c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4...)... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `explode` the (k,v)-array column and use `groupBy/agg` to dynamically aggregate `collect_list` over `id` and the list of distinct `c_*`, as in the following example:

```
case class kv(k: String, v: String)

val df = Seq(
  (1, Array(kv("k1", "v1"), kv("k2", "v2"), kv("k3", "v3")), "c_1"),
  (2, Array(kv("k1", "v1"), kv("k3", "v3"), kv("k5", "v5")), "c_2"),
  (3, Array(kv("k2", "v2"), kv("k4", "v4")), "c_1")
).toDF("id", "d", "c")
// +---+---------------------------+---+
// |id |d                          |c  |
// +---+---------------------------+---+
// |1  |[[k1,v1], [k2,v2], [k3,v3]]|c_1|
// |2  |[[k1,v1], [k3,v3], [k5,v5]]|c_2|
// |3  |[[k2,v2], [k4,v4]]         |c_1|
// +---+---------------------------+---+

// Assemble a list of distinct c_*
val cList = df.select($"c").map(_.getString(0)).collect.toList.distinct
// cList: List[String] = List(c_1, c_2)

df.withColumn("key_value", explode($"d")).
  groupBy($"key_value").agg(
    collect_list($"id").as("total_occ"),
    cList.map(x => collect_list(when($"c" === x, $"id")).as(s"${x}_occ")): _*
  ).
  orderBy($"key_value").
  show

// +---------+---------+-------+-------+
// |key_value|total_occ|c_1_occ|c_2_occ|
// +---------+---------+-------+-------+
// |  [k1,v1]|   [1, 2]|    [1]|    [2]|
// |  [k2,v2]|   [1, 3]| [1, 3]|     []|
// |  [k3,v3]|   [1, 2]|    [1]|    [2]|
// |  [k4,v4]|      [3]|    [3]|     []|
// |  [k5,v5]|      [2]|     []|    [2]|
// +---------+---------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For the step // Assemble a list of distinct c_* 
 I get this error """Error:(17, 43) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
    val cList = df.select(col("rule")).map(_.getString(0)).collect.toList.distinct""" 
but when I put cList=List(c_1,c_2,c_3) it works.I use spark 2.1.0

Comment: Glad that it helps.  As described in the error message, please make sure `import spark.implicits._` is there.